# Raspberry Pi 2 Windows 10 Iot App as Azure Service Bus receiver EventProcessor Host

Tags: c#, azure, windows-10, raspberry-pi2, azure-eventhub

I have followed the excellent article about service bus https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/  By Elio Damaggio.

Now I wanted to create the receiver in a Windows 10 App when is an IoT platform, but I cannot add the nuget package of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost.

```
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
```

Any idea how to solve this?

In case is there another library would someone post an small concise example like the article?

Comment: If it's anything other than a toy application, you probably don't want to have the IoT devices as receivers, as EventHubs are more designed for a potentially very large number of senders with relatively few receivers.

Answer (score 0):

The package you are trying to add has support for the .Net Core framework which is used in desktop applications but it (or one of its dependencies) doesn't have compatibility with the .Net Universal Windows framework.

If you can find the source code of the package you may be able to fork it to support Windows 10 Universal.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs which contains a C based API for Event Hubs. However, you will have to figure out how to compile it and the qpid-proton libraries it depends on for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

The library to be able to receive and send messages is: http://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureSBLite/ I have tested on Windows 10 and works both.
Apart includes several great examples:
https://github.com/ppatierno/azuresblite-examples

That is the library I was looking for, it is really easy to use.